# How to differentiate ZeroMQ packets from normal traffic

Tags: linux, networking, zeromq

I am simulating the following scenario:

> There are two routers, **A** and **B**, both with Internet access and also connected to each other via an internal private network (an Ethernet cable between them, basically). They each serve N clients (each router as its own client-side network). The routers send each other keepalive-like messages through a **ZeroMQ** publisher-subscriber scheme through the private network.
>
> Moreover, when **A** is congested, it must send its clients traffic
> to **B** (and vice-versa), which will forward that traffic to the Internet
> and thus "help" the congested router (temporarily).

Taking into account both routers are Linux, I suppose changing **A**'s default gateway to **B**'s private network interface IP would be enough to stir the traffic into **B** (through the common internal private network).

However, when **B** is receiving the traffic from **A**'s clients, it must be careful not to forward to the Internet (external network) the packages containing the messages exchanged between the ZeroMQ applications.

**My question is:** how can **B** know and differentiate, in the received packets, the ZeroMQ messages from the client packets (from **A**)?

Capturing with iptables/nfqueue and then analysing the packet? If so, what would identify a packet destined to the ZeroMQ app?

This is all considering that **B** will forward to the Internet (up) all packets received in the interface connected to the private network.

**Note:** I don't know if this is relevant for the question, but in the subscriber application, a filter is applied to the messages received. Every message beginning with "network_zmq" is captured by the subscriber.

**Edit:** I also exchange ICMP packets (ping) between the **A** and **B** (it's a requirement in my scenario). This means that ICMP requests from A to B must also not be forwarded to the Internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Q** : *How to differentiate ZeroMQ packets from normal traffic?*

Not so easy to answer a simple question. ZeroMQ is not about just sending some packets.

The ZeroMQ packets may use ( if going across a L3+ network infrastructure ) several different transport-class-es **`{ tcp:// | pgm:// | epgm:// | vmci:// }`**

If in such a need, one may introduce an app-side weak-labeling of such a packet-traffic, if one configures it to set the **`TOS`**-label for active declaration of such a marker `.setsockopt( ZMQ_TOS, aToS_VALUE )`

> <sub>Sets the ToS fields (Differentiated services (DS) and Explicit Congestion Notification (ECN) field of the IP header</sub>

---

> **Q** : *how can B know and differentiate, in the received packets, the ZeroMQ messages from the client packets (from A)?*

This part is harder. A weak, **`ToS`**-based detection is possible as noted above, the rest of the packet-processing depends on the L3+ ROUTER-software capabilities, not on the ZeroMQ as-is.

In case some client packets from A would have the same ToS-label as was intended to label the ZeroMQ-originated traffic, a typical L3+ ROUTER-software has no chance to distinguish between such cases ( it may build some heuristics and "guesstimate", yet IMHO the L3+ ROUTER software has since ever used to be primarily performance focused ( moving packets as fast as possible among the I/F ), not a "fully-programmable"-User-Defined-sniffer-Platform nor an adaptive-Policy-Enforcement-Platform )

Building a ZeroMQ-proxy ( Man-In-The-Middle ) may help you for cases no legally binding obligations are violated by injecting the MITM-node.